# Controlling service flow from the Caller method

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, coding-style

Is it correct to control how the service works from the caller of this service? I had such a problem today, and don't know if my solution is good or not. Hope someone more advanced can give me a feedback. Here is my problem:

I have got a service with method Foo:

```
public class Service
{
    public int? Foo(int? number, bool throwException)
    {
        int? result = number;

        if (result == null)
        {
              var result = ...
              if (result == null && throwException)
              {
                    throw new Exception("ZZZZ");
              }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Now in Caller class I got 2 methods where I invoke this Service:

```
public class Caller
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        ...         
        Service.Foo(number, TRUE);
        ...
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        ...         
        Service.Foo(number, FALSE);
        ...
    }
```

As you can see for Test1 im sending flag throwException TRUE, and for Test2 FALSE, is it good practice to control how the Service's flow go from the Caller's methods?

That's what i tried to avoid:

```
public class Caller
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        var a = Service.Foo1();
        if (a == something)
        {
              throw ARgumentException("ZZZ");
        }

        var b = Service.Foo2();
        if (b == something2)
        {
             throw ArgumentException("ZZZ2");
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach might become a problem when you need to throw different types of exceptions from `Service.Foo` method.

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov yes good point, but what do you think overall about controlling service method from the caller class? Good/Bad practise? I just did it because I invoke 2 methods like this in Caller so instead of having ~~10 lines (invoke + try catch + throw) i got just 2 lines. What version would you use?

Comment: I would say that it is better for caller to check for exceptions. You can create one method that handles all exceptions and then call it multiple times.

Comment: I just added edit to show what i tried to avoid with the "throwException" parameter to the service methods. It just looks ugly :/

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended by the Clean Code book to use "flag" (boolean) arguments. In this case you should make two methods in the service, one FooRequired() and one FooOrDefault(), or something like that.